# How to use Swift Package Manager with private repos?

Tags: git, swift-package-manager

How to use the Swift Package Manager with dependencies stored in private repositories?

Adding a `username` and `password` can functionally work:

```swift
let package = Package(
  name: "MyPackage",
  dependencies: [
    .package(url: "https://username:password@gitlab.com/me/MyPackage.git", .branch("develop"))     
  ]
)
```

However, the `username:password` approach has issues including (but not limited to) making the `Package.swift` username specified, and putting plain text credentials in the repository.

Ideally, a solution would:

1. not store any plain text or token credentials in the repository.
2. allow each team member to have their own credentials.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A solution, for Unix-like systems, is to use SSH `git` URLs and add `Host` configurations to `~/.ssh/config`.  This approach works for both macOS/Linux command line and Xcode.

*Use a ssh form for the dependency url in `Package.swift`.*

```swift
// swift-tools-version:4.0
import PackageDescription
    
let package = Package(
  name: "Example",
  dependencies: [
    .package(url: "git@gitlab.com.myteam:abc/private-repo.git", .branch("develop") ),
  ],
)
```

In the above example, `gitlab.com.myteam` corresponds to a `Host` in `~/.ssh/config`

```sh
### GITLAB  WorkTeamOne
Host gitlab.com.workteam
  HostName gitlab.com
  User git
  IdentityFile  ~/.ssh/my_work_key_rsa
  UseKeychain yes     # for macOS keychain
  AddKeysToAgent yes  # for macOS keychain
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
 
### GITLAB  Hobby
Host gitlab.com.hobby
  HostName gitlab.com
  User git
  IdentityFile  ~/.ssh/my_hobby_key_rsa
  UseKeychain yes     # for macOS keychain
  AddKeysToAgent yes  # for macOS keychain
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
```

Generate and apply SSH key pairs, as needed, for an individual's online git service account.

```sh
ssh-keygen \
   -b 4096 \
   -t rsa \
   -C "my_work_username@example.com" \
   -f ~/.ssh/my_work_key_rsa
```

Each team member could setup an individual, corresponding `Host` ssh configuration. The `Host` would be the same, however, the actual public/private key pairs (a) are specific to the user, (b) can be managed separately from any of the code development and (c) can be used automatically after the setup.

Comment: SSH part of your solution worked for me even without editing .ssh/config file with `github`. I've just changed `https://` link in the Package.swift file to `git@` link and since I've have my public key added to github it fetches well.

Comment: How do you convert Xcode project to use Package.swift instead of it's own Swift Package Manager GUI? Xcode does not allow to use SSH links for SPMs, or if it does, can some one explain how?

Comment: Raised this separately outlining latest attempts with latest Xcode 13 and even Apples supper useless tiny documentation copy.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69973853/how-to-setup-xcode-13-to-use-private-ssh-based-git-urls-for-swift-packages-depen

Comment: Can you provide details how to implement `Package.swift` with Xcode 13? 
To my understanding, you can only use/add `Package.swift` in SPMs, but not the main project, which is the question I believe raised here.

Comment: @Jonauz, `Package.swift` can be used for the root project in Xcode 13. Select the `Package.swift` file, then right-click and choose `Open With` > `Xcode` from the Finder Context Menu. _Xcode will open the `Package.swift` and assocated project directly._ See the `.swiftpm/xcode` directory for Xcode generated hidden project files. (FWIW, I create and edit the `Package.swift` files as a text file instead of using the Xcode GUI.)

Answer (score 36):

When using spm with private repos that are

- accessible via `vpn` or `proxies`,
- accessible via `ssh`
- with complex ~/ssh/config and /etc/hosts settings,

Note that Xcode keeps its own folder of `.ssh` and `known_hosts`.

You can see it in

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
```

It will look like this

[image]

In a ci environment, this is not pleasant and you might get the following errors:

> xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:
> The server SSH fingerprint failed to verify.

> xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:
> Authentication failed because the credentials were rejected

> An unknown error occurred. failed to connect to localhost: Connection refused (-1)

You can actually tell Xcode to use standard location of ssh keys and known hosts `~/.ssh` via one of the following:

a. This works on container based ci like [circle ci](https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360044709573-Swift-Package-Manager-fails-to-clone-from-private-Git-repositories)

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM YES
```

b. This works on bare metal

```
/usr/libexec/Plistbuddy -c "Add :IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM bool 1" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
```

c. If the above didn't work for you try adding `-scmProvider system` on your xcodebuild command

- [fastlane 2.169.0 supports this](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/17644)

```
gym(
    ...
    use_system_scm: true
)
```

```
scan(
    ...
    use_system_scm: true
)
```

- For running resolve dependencies with SPM having Private Repo

```
fastlane run spm --use_system_scm true
```

- non-fastlane users

```
xcodebuild -scmProvider system
```

Make sure your private repo host is added to `~/.ssh/known_hosts`

a. for bitbucket

```
for ip in $(dig @8.8.8.8 bitbucket.org +short); do ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org,$ip; ssh-keyscan $ip; done 2>/dev/null >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts || true
```

b. for github

```
for ip in $(dig @8.8.8.8 github.com +short); do ssh-keyscan github.com,$ip; ssh-keyscan $ip; done 2>/dev/null >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts || true
```

c. others

```
ssh-keyscan your-host.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: Thank you thank you a million times! FWIW I only needed the following (no sudo) on 'bare metal' (eg a vanilla mac with xcode installed): `defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM YES`

Comment: Exactly like Chris said. This resolved my issue on XCode 15.2. On 15.1 and earlier it would randomly break/work, but on 15.2 it didn't work *at all*. This command saved me. Note that you need to restart XCode after running it. I ran the "bare metal" one but I assume they do the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to build with a package from a private repo in GitHub actions with HTTPS URLs by creating a `.netrc` file using the `extractions/netrc@v1 action`.

```
  Build:
    runs-on: macos-12
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: extractions/netrc@v1
        with:
          machine: github.com
          username: user
          password: ${{ secrets.SWIFT_PACKAGE_MANAGER_PAT }}
      - uses: extractions/netrc@v1
        with:
          machine: api.github.com
          username: user
          password: ${{ secrets.SWIFT_PACKAGE_MANAGER_PAT }}
```

After this, `xcodebuild` will use the PAT when accessing the private repo.

I tried to use `GITHUB_TOKEN`, but it seems that it is restricted to the current repo only. So I created a PAT for a GitHub account that has access to the private repo and added that to the repo secrets.

Comment: You need to configure both `github.com` and `api.github.com`.  The username doesn't matter for the PAT, so just use `user`.

Answer (score 2):

I've made it without SSH for my iOS project in Xcode. My private repo with package hosted on GitLab, but can be hosted on GitHub, Bitbucket, self-hosted Gitlab.

The process is straight: create a private repo with SPM package on one of the hostings above. Then add it as a dependency in your Xcode project as a usual package. Since the repo is private, Xcode will ask for credentials (in case of Gitlab it's an access token which you can generate in your Gitlab account). Xcode will remember it and will authorize you next time automatically. Thus you (and your colleagues) have to enter credentials only one time at setup. And both of your 1 and 2 conditions are satisfied.

You can manage Source Control Accounts in Xcode -> Preference -> Accounts (press + for add one).

Answer (score 2):

I am using SPM with a private repo on GitHub.  I use the following in my package file:

```swift
let package = Package(
  name: "MyPackage",
  dependencies: [
    .package(url: "git@github.com:myusername/mypackage.git", .branch("develop"))     
  ]
)
```

Then I added a host to my ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile  ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
```

Then I added GitHub to the known hosts file by running the following on the command line:

```
ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Finally, I found that when compiling with swift on the command line, it didn't appear possible to use an SSH key with a passphrase so I created a new one without passphrase.

Comment: The passphrase part was really an issue for me, it's so annoying. Thanks for mention this.

Comment: Apple says the same, "**SSH-based Git URLs**", but they do not provide a way to do so, at least in **Xcode 13**.  I'm trying to find out how, and raised a question here for this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69973853/how-to-setup-xcode-13-to-use-private-ssh-based-git-urls-for-swift-packages-depen

Comment: @Jonauz Did you figure this out? There is no Package.swift and adding one doesn't do anything. I have the same issue where the GUI keeps reverting my URL to https.